# How to handle Assigned Id for ManyToOne refrences in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I have two entities like below - one with an auto generated ID and one more with Assigned Id.
Id of assignee is sent from request it self.
And i have ManyToOne relationship between them. But when i Insert it shows gives below error

```
"org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.example.entity.Task.assignee->com.example.entity.Assignee
```

Below Are my classes and annotations

```
package com.example.entity;
    @Data
    @Entity
    public class Task {
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
        @Id
        private UUID id;
        private String name;
        private String description;
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "assignee_id")
        private Assignee assignee;
    }

   
package com.example.entity;
    @Data
    @Entity
    public class Assignee implements Persistable<UUID> {
        @Id
        private UUID id;
        private String name;

    
        
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "assignee",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        @Transient
        private boolean isNew = true;
    
        @Override
        public boolean isNew() {
            return isNew;
        }
    
        @PrePersist
        @PostLoad
        void markNotNew() {
            this.isNew = false;
        }
    }
```

Below are my repository and service class which gets called from controller

```
@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, UUID> {
}


@Service
@Slf4j
public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {
 
    @Autowired
    TaskRepository taskRepository;
 
   @Override
    public Task create(Task request) {
        return taskRepository.save(task);
    }

    @Override
    public Task update(Task request) {
         return taskRepository.save(request);

    }
}
```

So when I send a request from postmen - like below

```
{
    "name": "test task",
    "description": "Do this task man",
    "assignee": {
        "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
        "name": "Lucia"
    }
}
```

So as i told task - has auto generated ID , where as Assignee ID is sent from caller of this API.  But i get below exception - when i call save method of repository. It is complaining to save assignee, but i have given Cascade.ALL
in the mapping of entity.

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.example.entity.Task.assignee->com.example.entity.Assignee
```

Comment: Please provide more code/data/information.

Comment: @xerx593 given all details.

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong, why are you creating assignee and then adding it to task?  where assignee `Id` is coming from? Isn't it from your database ?

Comment: That's what i'm saying. Assignee - has assigned Id-  its not generated.
i dont want to generate it in my application. Basically assignee is User and Front end service takes it from some other microservice and it just sends it to me.